# Artefacts with Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I try to learn Eevee and I noticed that I have a lot of artifacts in my viewport when I opened old projects. These artifacts can also be found in newly created scenes. 
[image]
When I render this scene, there are big "holes". Why is that? [image]
Is this a bug or is it due to my computer (I don't have a graphics card, just a laptop with Core i5 -7200U CPU)?
It's not the normals, they're correct.

Comment: Looks like a glitch caused by a graphics driver bug. Try to update your graphics driver. https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29074/Intel-Grafik-Windows-10-DCH-Treiber?product=95443

Comment: Thanks, but there is no newer driver available.

The render error is even present when trying to render the default cube of a new scene.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken your CPU and integrated GPU *are supported* and meet the minimum requirements. Could you check if the problem persists in the most recent experimental build (https://builder.blender.org/download/)?  Just use if for testing, you can delete it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, but it's the same in 2.81.

I have experimented now, when I turn on screen space reflections, it will be rendered clean. I don't understand why this is necessary, but at the moment this is fine for me.

Comment: I can see there have been some bug reports that may be related, but not an exact match as far as I can tell and nothing that is for your particular integrated GPU. Are you using Windows, Linux or macOS?

Comment: I use Windows 10

Comment: Then please do the following to create a good bug report. Open the installation folder of Blender and search for `blender_debug_gpu.cmd`. Double click on it, this will start Blender in a debug mode and write a log file. When Blender has started, try to reproduce the graphic glitch, then close Blender. It will give show you two files in the Windows Explorer afterwards, copy them to a folder where you will remember them. Then go back to the installation folder of Blender and search for `blender_debug_gpu_glitchworkaround.cmd`.

Comment: Double click on it to start Blender. Check if you can still reproduce the glitches. Then in Blender use *Help > Report a Bug*. Register on the bug tracker and write the bug report. Make sure to give step by step instruction on how to reproduce the problem (meaning what settings have you enabled, what buttons where clicked etc.). Attach the log files from the beginning either by drag & drop or by clicking on the little cloud icon. Add to the report whether or not the glitch workaround helped.

Comment: If I start blender with blender_debug_gpu_glitchworkaround.cmd I cannot reproduce the glitch anymore. Viewport and render are clean.

Comment: Would be great if you could report the bug anyway.

Comment: Done 
https://developer.blender.org/T70847

Answer (score 1):

It was a driver problem. The affected computer model is from the ASUS UX410 series. The Intel update refuses to install the new driver and refers to a customized driver from the manufacturer. However, the automatic update function of the manufacturer does not find the new Intel driver, but it is listed on the manufacturer's website.

I installed the driver and the problem was fixed. There are no artifacts in the viewport now and the render is clean.